# Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=x^2 + y^2$, $x+z=0$ - correctness of solution

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Please check, whether my solution is correct.

Task: Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=x^2 + y^2$, $x+z=0$

We need to calculate $\iint \limits_D - x - (x^2 + y^2 ) dx dy$, where
$D = \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 = -x\} = \{(x,y): (x+\frac{1}{2})^2 + y^2 = (\frac{1}{2})^2  \}$.

Easiest solution: change coordinates to polar.

$\psi \in (\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2})$

$ (x+\frac{1}{2})^2 + y^2 = (\frac{1}{2})^2$

$ (r \cos(\psi)+\frac{1}{2})^2 + (r \sin(\psi))^2 = (\frac{1}{2})^2$

$r(r + \cos(\psi)) = 0$, so

$r \in (0, -\cos(\psi))$

$\iint \limits_D - x - (x^2 + y^2 ) dx dy = \int \limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \int \limits_0^{-cos \psi }  r [-r \cos \psi  - r^2 \cos^2 \psi - r^2 \sin^2 \psi ] dr d\psi= ...$

Comment: Looks good so far.

Comment: That is correct. Go on!

Comment: The rest is fairly easy :) Thank you for your help!